# How do I align 2 divs (each has its own padding) next to each other?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

With the padding commented out as shown, the website works like I'd expect (2 div columns next to each other.

However, when I add padding, the #right div **shifts downwards**. How would I make it work as intended with padding?

**HTML:** Two divs contained directly in body

**CSS:**

```
#left {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 70%;
}

#right {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 30%;
}

#left, #right {
    //padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

> box-sizing: border-box;

to your divs.

If you don't the padding is added outside the div width (or height).. same as borders

Edited: and

> -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

for a bit more browser compatibility

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. May I ask for a quick explanation?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using css3 , you can use `box-sizing: border-box;`

else, you can have another child `div` and apply `padding` to the child `div` instead of the parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

```css
#left {
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 70%;
}
#right {
 background-color: blue;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 30%;
}
#left, #right {
 padding: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 800px;
 color:#fff;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"> left </div>
<div id="right"> right </div>
```